# Batch script to resize height of all layers to same height but keeping their original aspect ratio

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing, photoshop-scripting

I have hundreds of product image layers and I am trying to resize them all to the same height (ignoring the width) and retaining their individual aspect ratio's.

Is there a script available that does this? Or a feature I am unaware of?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please show some sample images that show exactly what you are trying to do. Are the images currently all different dimensions?  It might have been better to batch resize them before you put them in layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do can be done with actions and batch.

- (1) Go to your actions tab (Window>Actions if its not already on your workspace).
- (2) (a.) Create a new action set.  (b.) Create a new action.
- (3) Rename it and hit record.
- (4) Your action should be recording.
- (5) Change your image size: 
    You will first want to check your resolution to make sure each image is the same, otherwise if you combine your images into the same document, they will still be different sizes.
    (c.) Make sure your aspect ratio is locked. And change your height dimensions.
- Click ok.
- (6) (d.) Go back to the action panel and press stop (Square button to the left of the record)

[image]

Now you can do a batch automation.

- (1) Go to File>Automate>Batch
- (2) Make sure your new action is selected. Chose your source folder (The location of the images you wish to change)
- You can just save the document and close or chose a new destination folder.
- Now you can just let it do its thing.

[image]

I'm not sure what you meant by image layers though. (It sounds like you are talking about layers in a particular document??)
Above, I'm assuming you have a folder full of images of all different dimensions and want to resize them so that every image is height = x.